# Не выводится шорткод в js

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, шорткод, shortcode

Есть сайт на WordPress. Стоит задача вывести шорткод в нескольких местах в шаблоне. В некоторых php файлах вывести получилось вот таким методом:

```
elseif(!empty($deafaultFeatImg)){echo do_shortcode( '[featured-video-plus]' );
```

Но при добавлении в другом месте (в файле под названием "main.js") таким образом:
    var popLeftSide = '' + '' +''echo do_shortcode( '[featured-video-plus]' );'' +'' +...

страница подгружается не полностью и, соответственно, сам шорткод не выводится. Если таким образом:

```
var popLeftSide = '<div class="col-md-6 lp-insert-data">' + '<div class="lp-grid-box-thumb">' + '<div class="slide">[featured-video-plus]</div>' +...
```

то шорткод не срабатывает - выводится просто текстом: [featured-video-plus].

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Это дополненный код:`

```
    jQuery('#listing-preview-popup .md-close').hide();
    var docHeight = jQuery( document ).height();
    jQuery( "body" ).prepend( '<div id="full-overlay"></div>' );
    jQuery('#full-overlay').css('height',docHeight+'px');

    jQuery('#listing-preview-popup .popup-inner-left-padding').html('').css('min-hegiht', '300px');

    if(jQuery('#listing-preview-popup').is('.md-show')) {

    }else{
        jQuery('#listing-preview-popup').modal({
            show: 'true'
        });
        jQuery('#listing-preview-popup').addClass('md-show');
    }

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajax_search_term_object.ajaxurl,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            'action':'quick_preivew_cb',
            'LPpostID' : LPpostID
        },
        success:function(data) {
            jQuery('#listing-preview-popup .md-close').show().children('i').css('right', '20px');

         var ad_markup = '';
         var rate_markup = '';
         if(data.noreview){
             rate_markup = data.noreview;
         }
            if(data.adStatus == 'active')
            {
                ad_markup = '<span class="listing-pro">'+data.ad+'</span>';
            }
            if(data.rate != ''){
             rate_markup = '<span class="rate">'+ data.rate +'<sup>/5</sup></span>'
}
         var popLeftSide = '<div class="col-md-6 lp-insert-data">' +
 '<div class="lp-grid-box-thumb">' +
  '<div class="slide"><?php echo do_shortcode( '[featured-video-plus]' ); ?></div>' +
 '</div>' +
 '<div class="lp-grid-desc-container lp-border clearfix">' +
  '<div class="lp-grid-box-description ">' +
   '<div class="lp-grid-box-left pull-left">' +
    '<h4 class="lp-h4"><a href="'+ data.permalink +'">'+ ad_markup + LPtitle +'</a></h4>' +
    '<ul>' +
     '<li>'+ rate_markup +'</li>';
     if(data.pricey!=null){
         popLeftSide +='<li class="middle">' + data.pricey +'</li>';
     }

     popLeftSide += '<li>' + data.cats_markup +'</li>' +
     '<li>' +
      '<a href="tel:'+ data.phone +'">'+ data.phone +'</a>' +
     '</li>' +
    '</ul>';
    if(data.post_content!=false){
        popLeftSide +=
        '<div class="lp-grid-desc">' +
        '<p>'+ data.post_content +'</p>' +
        '</div>';
    }
    popLeftSide +=
   '</div>' +
   '<div class="lp-grid-box-right pull-right"></div>' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div class="lp-grid-box-bottom">' +
   '<div class="pull-left">' + data.adress_markup +'</div>' +
   '<div class="pull-right">' +
    '<a class="status-btn">'+ data.openStatus +'</a>' +
   '</div>' +
   '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
  '</div>' +
 '</div>' +
'</div>';

            var rightSideMarkup = '<div class="col-md-6">' +
  '<div id="quickmap'+ LPpostID +'" class="quickmap"></div>';
 '</div>';
            jQuery('#listing-preview-popup .popup-inner-left-padding').html(popLeftSide + rightSideMarkup);
            var markers = false;
            $mtoken = jQuery('#page').data("mtoken");
            $defpinURL = jQuery('.lp-grid-box-contianer').data("lppinurl");
            $lat = LPlattitue;
            $lan = LPlongitute;

            if($mtoken != ''){

                L.mapbox.accessToken = $mtoken;
                map = L.mapbox.map('quickmap'+LPpostID, 'mapbox.streets');
            }else{
                var map = new L.Map('quickmap'+LPpostID, {center: new L.LatLng($lat,$lan), zoom: 14});
                var googleLayer = new L.Google('ROADMAP');
                map.addLayer(googleLayer);
            }

            map.setView([$lat,$lan], 14);

            markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

            var markerLocation = new L.LatLng($lat, $lan); // London

            var CustomHtmlIcon = L.HtmlIcon.extend({
                options : {
                    html : "<div class='lpmap-icon-shape pin lp-default-map-pin-img'><div class='lpmap-icon-contianer'><img src='"+$defpinURL+"'></div></div>",
                }
            });

            var customHtmlIcon = new CustomHtmlIcon();

            var marker = new L.Marker(markerLocation, {icon: customHtmlIcon}).bindPopup('').addTo(map);
            markers.addLayer(marker);
            jQuery('.md-close.widget-map-click').on('click', function(e){
                            jQuery('#full-overlay').remove();
            });
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция do_shortcode() возвращает строку с результатом выполнения шорткода. Поэтому, если вы просто поместите текст шорткода, он и выведется как текст. Чудес не бывает.

В вашем втором случае я вообще не понимаю, что вы делаете. Похоже, что вы пытаетесь впихнуть функцию php в js код. Это не может работать в принципе. Предположу, что это часть php кода, в котором формируется js скрипт. Тогда надо примерно так:

```
var popLeftSide = '<div class="col-md-6 lp-insert-data">' + '<div class="lp-grid-box-thumb">' +'<div class="slide"><?php echo do_shortcode( '[featured-video-plus]' ); ?></div>' +'</div>' +...
```

Comment: Прошу прощения. Вы правы. Вставляю в файл main.js. Но ваш вариант не сработал, страница подгружается не полностью.

Comment: Я вам не полный код привел, а такой же обрезанный, как вы привели в вопросе. Как может работать код, который заказчивается на ... ? Я вам идею дал - вставлять надо в операторных скобках php, дальше уже самому думать. Ну или вопрос задавать с полным кодом.

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Естественно, мой код не сработал. Потому что я предплагал, что вы пытаетесь вставить js скрипт в php файле. А оказывается, у вас js скрипт, который вы пытаетесь модифицировать. Вы хотите того, что не бывает в принципе. js-код выполняется в браузере, а php - на сервере. Вы НИКАК не вставите туда шорткод напрямую. Читайте, что такое ajax, как его реализовать в WordPress https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html, разбирайте свой js код, в котором уже есть ajax, добавляйте в возвращаемый объект data поле с результатом вашего шорткода, и вставляйте уже это поле в popLeftSide.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.